# Retag [aws-sam-local] to [aws-sam-cli]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The AWS SAM Local project (a CLI for developing serverless applications) has been renamed to AWS SAM CLI:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli

Is there a moderator who would be willing to retag [aws-sam-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-local) to [aws-sam-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-cli) to reflect this?

Here is a GitHub pull request review where one of the authors of that project has expressed interest in renaming the tag as well:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/pull/409#pullrequestreview-119899942

Comment: As a SAM user, your input [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381870/is-aws-cloudformation-allowed-here) would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [aws-sam-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-cli) was *already* created, and therefore a simple rename couldn't be done here. The [aws-sam-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-local) had a clean tag wiki, and was followed by 26 people, whereas [aws-sam-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-cli) was a new one with just 20 questions. In order to preserve both the wiki and the followers:

1. I retagged all the questions with [aws-sam-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-cli) to use [aws-sam-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-local) automatically.
2. I renamed the tag [aws-sam-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-local) to [aws-sam-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-cli).
3. I added [aws-sam-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-local) as a synonym to [aws-sam-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam-cli).

And now the job is done. There is another [aws-sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sam), but that is for another day.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @BhargavRao. I think, probably, having `aws-sam` is ok as it has two components, a 'Translator` service in Amazon, and a separate project for the CLI. Personally, I think a single tag `aws-sam` would be perfect. Failing that, I suppose, `aws-sam` could be for the service, and `aws-sam-cli` could be for the CLI project.

Comment: We _can_ potentially rename `aws-sam` to `aws-sam-service`, but I'd rather leave it to the top users in that (and related) tag to decide.

Comment: Yeah I don't think `aws-sam-service` is intuitive. I personally don't see the need for 2 tags at all, and I would be in favour of just rolling all of `aws-sam-cli` into `aws-sam`, but if there are to be 2 tags, then the existing names are most intuitive to me. But I agree, the OP should decide.

Answer (score 0):

As a SAM user, I was also confused why there is an `aws-sam-local` and an `aws-sam-cli` tag. This change should be made.