# Is AWS CloudFormation allowed here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I ask this question as a result of high-rep SO users often voting-to-close on AWS CloudFormation questions, arguing that the questions belong at Server Fault.<sup>1</sup>

The immediate context is two users voting-to-close on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992569/template-format-error-unsupported-structure-seen-in-aws-cloudformation) question - a frequently-asked question - stating in their close reason:

> Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

As someone with expertise in this technology, this thinking is obviously wrong to me, for many reasons:

1. AWS CloudFormation is a declarative [DSL](https://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html), with programming features such as [functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html), [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), Lambda-backed [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html), etc.
2. AWS CloudFormation templates are YAML or JSON documents, requiring knowledge of one or both of these of the user. Advanced features of YAML like tags etc are used.
3. AWS CloudFormation is used, among other things, to deploy Serverless Applications (Lambda functions, API Gateways etc) into the AWS Cloud.
4. AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) is a superset of AWS CloudFormation. SAM is obviously on-topic at SO, ergo so is CloudFormation.
5. AWS CloudFormation is not a technology that is suitable for system administrators without development expertise. I.e., it's really difficult.
6. There are already [3,000+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation) questions tagged `amazon-cloudformation`.
7. This technology has been discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341927/merge-cloudformation-into-amazon-cloudformation?r=SearchResults&s=1|75.6015) [at](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348988/merge-the-3-amazon-cloudformation-tags?r=SearchResults&s=2|64.6074) [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cloudformation) [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343482/there-s-more-of-the-amazon-to-cut-down?r=SearchResults&s=5|28.0311) and no one has suggested these questions belong at SF.

It is argued in comments that users would be "better served" at Server Fault. Well:

- At the time of writing, there are [202](https://serverfault.com/tags/amazon-cloudformation/topusers) questions in total on CloudFormation in SF, compared to [3,138](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-cloudformation/topusers) here.
- In the last 30 days, there have been 4 questions asked at SF, compared to **130** here.
- We have people like [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) (Sr Technical Trainer at AWS); and [Dr. Will Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518355/wjordan) answering questions here.

Clearly, it is *not* true that people are better served by asking their questions at Server Fault.

In summary, these questions belong at SO because:

- AWS CloudFormation is a [tool](https://dev.to/brightdevs/how-to-deploy-lambda-function-with-cloudformation-4id5) [used](https://itnext.io/how-to-build-an-api-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-using-cloudformation-bd5f9249ac2f) [by](https://medium.com/nikeengineering/safely-deploy-aws-lambdas-with-cloudformation-d0ee829d8351) [developers](https://nodesource.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-monitoring-aws-lambda-serverless) [to](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/09/07/continuous-deployment-aws-lambda-behind-api-gateway/) [deploy](https://dzone.com/articles/java-on-the-aws-cloud-using-lambda-api-gateway-and) [their](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/31/use-aws-cloudformation-to-automate-static-site-deployment-with-s3) [apps](https://course.fast.ai/deployment_aws_lambda.html) [in](https://medium.com/@ngchiwang/aws-apigateway-deployment-not-update-3e04fcffe85b) [the](https://www.devalias.net/devalias/2018/09/15/forming-serverless-clouds-aws-cloudformation-sam-cdk-amplify/) [cloud](https://www.ocelotconsulting.com/2017/12/18/lambda-gateway.html).
- AWS CloudFormation is rarely a tool used by professional server administrators
- AWS CloudFormation is a domain-specific language and is thus programming.
- It is the clear consensus of both the greater number of answerers here, and the vastly greater number of questions asked here, that SO seems the natural home for these questions *to most people*.

So:

**Are AWS CloudFormation questions still allowed at SO?**

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note I have not seen any questions ever successfully closed before, but people keep trying.</sub>

Comment: *"Note I have not seen any questions ever successfully closed before, but people keep trying."* so then there's no problem, I think?

Comment: @Stijn, it would be better if there was a clear yes/no answer to refer to on whether or not certain technologies belong here, or elsewhere.

Comment: Many of these arguments could be made about other server infrastructure technologies, and yet many times questions about these technologies might have a better home at Server Fault. Although these can be said to be tools "used by developers", this is not enough to pass the topicality test. It should also be a _"practical answerable problem **unique to software development**_.

Comment: _AWS CloudFormation is rarely a tool used by professional server administrators_. I disagree with this.

Comment: How much CloudFormation experience do you have @yivi? People who are not programmers simply can't use this tech, end of story. I've seen it often, and as an Amazon partner, this is a consensus.

Comment: I have some CloudFormation experience, and I know a couple of system administrators that use it.

Comment: Well no one who is not a developer can be hired where I am to use this tech.

Comment: Some system administrators are actually very good developers, so that doesn't mean much.

Comment: That's great. Logically the skillset of system administrators and developers overlaps in some areas, as it should. That doesn't mean a question should be posted in one site or the other.

Comment: How about all the points I made. It's a programming language.

Comment: Questions specific about the DSL aspect could be on-topic, maybe. Question about other aspects (as interpreting error outputs for CLI usage), maybe aren't.

Comment: I'm not saying all questions about "using the CLI" should be posted on Server Fault. That wouldn't make any sense. My comment was referring specifically to AWS CLI tool usage, to make an example.

Comment: How about instead of us inventing new rules in this conversation, we interpret the existing rules. Is AWS CloudFormation a "developer tool" (yes). Is it a DSL (yes). Is it primarily used by _SERVER_ administrators? No. Because there are no servers, that's the whole point.

Comment: So, it appears you've come into this `discussion` with your mind made up about the topicality of AWS CloudFormation questions. Your interactions with @yivi leave the impression that you are passionate about the product. That's great! But if you want to have a discussion about its place in the scope of SO, please keep an open mind.

Comment: Yes that's true. I don't think anyone is likely to convince me that AWS CloudFormation is a tool primarily used by server administrators, because I'm a consultant and an Amazon partner and that's just simply and completely false. Yet here we are,

Comment: I do not believe it’s a “developer tool”. No more than nginx is. I believe that is a service used primarily by server (you can replace that with “infrastructure” to it makes it easier to understand) administrators primarily.

Comment: Alright. Let others decide then.

Comment: My opinion is (because I don't make decisions for other people): these questions can be on-topic, but will likely be better served on other sites. The goal is to ask where you have the better chance of getting quality answers. That opinion pretty much shadows what you see happening with those close votes: it's very much not crystal clear, you have to really think about the on-topicness of these matters. The end result is: regular close votes trickling in from people who think otherwise. IMO... hard evidence that the system actually works.

Comment: @Gimby, "likely be better served on other sites". Really? There are [202](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation?sort=newest) questions on it in total over there. Compared to 3,000+ here. Top users [shows](https://serverfault.com/tags/amazon-cloudformation/topusers) there is literally one frequent answerer over there, an AWS-certified guy that sorry I haven't heard of. I'm sure he's good. But you'll be better served over here, getting answers from real developers.

Comment: It's hard to have a constructive debate when the asker's already made up their mind and refuses to accept any arguments that doesn't support their view.

Comment: More questions are asked about anything in SO. But if you look at it proportionally, it's a different story: 202/271756 = 0.07% of questions are about AWS in SF. In SO? 3138/17389060 = 0.01%. And you have 25% unanswered on SF vs 35% unanswered on SO, making it seem is more likely a question will get an answer on SF than on SO. What does all this prove? Nothing.

Comment: @fbueckert, I don't see any debate above. A PHP developer asserts that CloudFormation is analogous to Nginx. What am I supposed to say to that? It's falsely claimed that better help is available at SF, which doesn't stand up to a few seconds of checking. AWS CloudFormation has always been here, and belongs here. It isn't debatable as far as I can tell.

Comment: "AWS CloudFormation provides a common language for you to **describe and provision all the infrastructure resources in your cloud environment**. CloudFormation allows you to use a **simple text file to model and provision**, in an automated and secure manner, all the resources needed for your applications across all regions and accounts. This file serves as the single source of truth for your cloud environment." Why, yes, that sounds like software development and not infrastructure management.

Comment: @Will, you are cherry-picking some lines from Amazon's docs that make it sound more about infrastructure than about development. Doing that doesn't refute any of the long list of points I made (it's a DSL; it's a tool used primarily by developers to deploy their apps in the cloud, etc).

Comment: Lol, "cherry picking". I guess we'll have to defer to you as to what it is rather than listen to mfing Amazon https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/ I cherry picked that first paragraph from the gdamn landing page, all right.

Comment: @Will, you're quoting from a marketing document and ignoring that it is a DSL and ignoring numerous links I provided that shows it is a tool used by developers frequently for deploying their Serverless apps into the AWS Cloud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are ansible/puppet/chef/salt questions on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294923/are-ansible-puppet-chef-salt-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No one has answered, although I discovered [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295044/3787051) accepted, related, 18-times-upvoted answer that, to me, answers this question too by close analogy:

I'll quote that author at length:

> If it's about programming Ansible / Puppet / Chef / Salt to do a specific task, it's on topic. The fact that they are all (in one sense or another) declarative languages for which it is easy to write language extensions doesn't matter. Otherwise, all sql-related questions would be off-topic here, as would discussions about constraint-based languages like prolog, and questions about configuration issues with logging frameworks like logback.
>
> There is a lot of overlap in these tags with ServerFault too, but that's just the way of the network. Different communities already have the same problem. Should I ask my bash-related question on Stackoverflow, Unix and Linux, Ask Ubuntu, Ask Different, ServerFault, or SuperUser for example? It depends on the specific context of my question (does it fit the standards of the community) and which community I find the easiest to understand.

If I substitute AWS CloudFormation (or AWS SAM, AWS CDK or for that matter new DSLs like Terraform, Troposphere, SparkleFormation etc), all of the same considerations apply here too.

Of course, AWS CloudFormation is also a [tool](https://dev.to/brightdevs/how-to-deploy-lambda-function-with-cloudformation-4id5) [used](https://itnext.io/how-to-build-an-api-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-using-cloudformation-bd5f9249ac2f) [by](https://medium.com/nikeengineering/safely-deploy-aws-lambdas-with-cloudformation-d0ee829d8351) [developers](https://nodesource.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-monitoring-aws-lambda-serverless) [to](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/09/07/continuous-deployment-aws-lambda-behind-api-gateway/) [deploy](https://dzone.com/articles/java-on-the-aws-cloud-using-lambda-api-gateway-and) [their](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/31/use-aws-cloudformation-to-automate-static-site-deployment-with-s3) [apps](https://course.fast.ai/deployment_aws_lambda.html) [in](https://medium.com/@ngchiwang/aws-apigateway-deployment-not-update-3e04fcffe85b) [the](https://www.devalias.net/devalias/2018/09/15/forming-serverless-clouds-aws-cloudformation-sam-cdk-amplify/) [cloud](https://www.ocelotconsulting.com/2017/12/18/lambda-gateway.html), which gives it far more reason to be here than, say, Ansible, another YAML DSL, but one which truly is used mostly for configuring infrastructure.

Thus, if AWS CloudFormation was ruled off-topic for SO, half of what is asked here would have to go with it, and there would be a [great disturbance in the Force](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKu7TYWNxqA).

Comment: I don't think it deserves to be here far more than any of the other tags, they're all in the group of tags that have the unfortunate characteristic of walking the fine line of dev/ops - it has just as much right to be here, or just as little depending on your personal beliefs. Other than that, don't really know why this answer is attracting downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a matter of domain expertise?  Is it a product of our convention to want code we can run locally?  Do we just *not* understand AWS enough to be able to say authoritatively that we can answer these questions?

I personally do think that these questions are on topic for Stack Overflow...

- They concern a service which has an API and allows us to leverage that API
- It's not the case that a typical sysadmin would be touching this configuration; these are more developers configuring the service more than sysadmins

...but I'm not convinced that we at Stack Overflow actually have any of the prerequisite knowledge to be able to actually answer this question at all.  It kind of languishes in the ether, without much in the way of guidance or actual expertise (and I'm not really sure where those experts are hiding, since [AWS questions are tough to get an answer to, apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53841027/1079354)).

For now, I say yes they're allowed.  But I would also champion a new Area 51 proposal which created a new Stack Exchange site dedicated *explicitly* to it.

Comment: I would not support a new SE site. A few reasons: DevOps stands for breaking down siloes, not creating new ones. It also stands for inclusion, rather than excluding people. A dedicated site is the opposite of all this, and I don't think it will be supported. It _might_ be supported in Meta, but I doubt it will be used by AWS experts. It also has been tried before, and it didn't work. On your AWS Glue question, only a handful of people in the world could answer that, and most of them are in the Glue team in Amazon. It doesn't really mean much. I actually did a PoC using Glue 6 months ago.

Comment: Puppet also [tried](https://ask.puppet.com) this and gave up. Stack Overflow always wins. It's where everyone wants to be.

Comment: See also my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380645/3787051).